# How can I find the user of a tiktok link like “https://vm.tiktok.com/ZMLSAuJCY/“?

Tags: hyperlink, tiktok

It just redirects me to tiktok.com when I put it in my browser. Can someone explain to me the solution in simple terms? I do not know programming.

Thanks Stack Community!